# Pyglet not running properly on AMD HD4250

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I am building an python program using pyglet. The source code runs just fine on any computer exept for my laptop. My Laptop is also the only one with a AMD graphics card: the HD4250. Its Xubuntu 13.04 AMD64, and the graphics drivers are the X11 Open Source ones. This is how it looks:
[image]

When adding a clear statement in the constructor the screen gets build properly, but then is incredebly slow. It will refresh at max 2 times per 30 seconds and barely respond to any input. How can I fix this?

It does not seem that OpenGL is the problem: when using Qt OpenGL (C++ also) there are no problems like this at all.

Some (hopefully relevant) code:

```
def draw(self):
        pyglet.text.Label('Start Screen',
                          font_name='Arial',
                          font_size=16,
                          x=self.window.get_size()[0]/2, y=self.window.get_size()[1]-20,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center').draw()

        pyglet.text.Label('This side is looking at the enemy',
                          font_name='Arial',
                          font_size=16,
                          x=self.window.get_size()[0]/2, y=self.window.get_size()[1]-60,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center').draw()

        pyglet.text.Label(self.bottumText,
                          font_name='Arial',
                          font_size=16,
                          x=self.window.get_size()[0]/2, y=20,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center').draw()

        for y in range(0, len(self.fields)):
            for field in self.fields[y]:

                if (field.selected):
                    glColor3f(self.color[0], self.color[1], self.color[2])
                    # glColor3f(1, 0, 1)
                else:
                    glColor3f(1, 1, 1)

                # Draw center
                # self.drawCircle(field.x, field.y, 5, [1, 1, 1])

                # # Draw top side
                pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, ('v2i', 
                    (field.x + field.size, field.y + field.size, 
                    field.x - field.size, field.y + field.size)))

                # Draw down side
                pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, ('v2i', 
                    (field.x + field.size, field.y - field.size, 
                    field.x - field.size, field.y - field.size)))

                # Draw left side
                pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, ('v2i', 
                    (field.x - field.size, field.y - field.size,
                    field.x - field.size, field.y + field.size)))

                # Draw right side
                pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, ('v2i', 
                    (field.x + field.size, field.y - field.size,
                    field.x + field.size, field.y + field.size)))
```

Comment: I guess if you comment out all the "operations" and go through them one by one you still get the same problem? for instance start with `pyglet.text.Label('Start Screen'` and leave the rest commented out. If you get the same problem i assume you should be looking at how you `clear()` the screen and how you update the userspace (for instance `flip()`) :)

Comment: If one of the statements are added (labels, line drawing, no matter which) it happens. If I replace the entire thing with pass, it gives a black screen, which looks fine. I use self.clear() as clear function and no flip() at all.

Comment: Ok so the problem is obviously not with what you render, (lables etc) because that worked with my code. Can you post your rendering  code (everything from clear() to the last row in the same blow)? usually it's within `def on_draw(self):`

Comment: The code in the OP is exactly what gets drawn. I only call clear once, when constructing the Window object. When I call clear on every draw you can see the screen build (takes about 2 seconds) every single time and it responds really slow to any input. But on the other hand: the screen looks fine.

Comment: How much FPS did you get out of my application below?
try adding a `self.flip()` at the end of your draw function?

Comment: Your application gave me 20-25 FPS. If I add flip at the end of every draw the program gets really slow on every computer it runs on.

Comment: Can you post all your code? i bet there's a sleep or something in there that messes things up but i'm sorry i can't help you without your code, or if you just steal my code and add your stuff in `draw()` to my `render()` function?

Comment: I rewrote big parts, I disabled the double buffer for some reason and I now properly redraw everything. The code now runs okay, with 5 FPS. But no more sluggish, behaviour or artefacts, jsut some bad written code I guess. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30015/discussion-between-torxed-and-cheiron)

Comment: You're welcome! :) Gl with the adventures!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the following code produce:
(It's not limited to a certain frame buffer per se so it might produce better output)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyglet
from time import time, sleep

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, refreshrate):
        super(Window, self).__init__(vsync = False)
        self.frames = 0
        self.framerate = pyglet.text.Label(text='Unknown', font_name='Verdana', font_size=8, x=10, y=10, color=(255,255,255,255))
        self.last = time()
        self.alive = 1
        self.refreshrate = refreshrate
        self.click = None
        self.drag = False

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        self.click = x,y

    def on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
        if self.click:
            self.drag = True
            print 'Drag offset:',(dx,dy)

    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        if not self.drag and self.click:
            print 'You clicked here', self.click, 'Relese point:',(x,y)
        else:
            print 'You draged from', self.click, 'to:',(x,y)
        self.click = None
        self.drag = False

    def render(self):
        self.clear()
        if time() - self.last >= 1:
            self.framerate.text = str(self.frames)
            self.frames = 0
            self.last = time()
        else:
            self.frames += 1
        self.framerate.draw()
        self.flip()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            self.render()
            # ----> Note: <----
            #  Without self.dispatc_events() the screen will freeze
            #  due to the fact that i don't call pyglet.app.run(),
            #  because i like to have the control when and what locks
            #  the application, since pyglet.app.run() is a locking call.
            event = self.dispatch_events()
            sleep(1.0/self.refreshrate)

win = Window(23) # set the fps
win.run()
```

You could try to force specific drawing methods that might work with the open driver you're using, stuff like:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```

and

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
glLoadIdentity()
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
glVertex2f(0, 0)
glVertex2f(window.width, 0)
glVertex2f(window.width, window.height)
glEnd()
```

Comment: This code works great, I am currently looking into making the code more basic OpenGLish, I hope it helps.

Comment: It probably has to do with something in the textures that you load and the way you batch or not batch render them. Perhaps the batch is to big etc? It's just ideas but I hope any of my stuff contributes to solving your problem (without me knowing anything about your code) :)

Comment: I do not use any textures, all I'm drawing is lines and labels