# Game development using python object oriented approach.

Tags: python, oop, pygame

I am looking for online resource or any good e-book for developing the small games using python language with object orientated approach . my objective is to create small games in class/object fashion.

I googled it but didn't get any good link.

can anybody knows about good resource to start?

Answer (score 3):

Look into Kivy (mobile/cross-platform--which uses PyGame) or PyGame for game development modules. Python is an object-oriented language so *mostly* everything created python should be object-oriented naturally.

Just some references to get you started:

PyGame:http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-learn-pygame--cms-24184

Kivy Docs: https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html

Alexander Taylor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7UKmK9eQLY

Comment: Thanks.but  at beginner level , i would not like to work with any kind of framework . I didn't find any resource which develop game with pyGame lib using oops concept.

Comment: @YADAV - PyGame has classes `Sprite`, `Group`, `Rect` but it is low-level library and you have to create other classes on your own - `Button`, `Player`, `Enemy`, `Obstacle`, etc. You rather can't do game without PyGame, Kivy, Pyglet, Cocos2d-Python, PySFML.

Comment: Thanks.. agreed with you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, these types of questions usually get closed quickly because "help me find a tool, book or resource" is generally not welcome.

That said we do our best to help anyway before questions get shut down.

I would recommend Pygame if you're a beginner, otherwise I'd suggest `Pyglet` every day of the week.

I just posted a good example yesterday of how you can OOP some OpenGL stuff that can be used for games that I think work really well. I also gave a semi descent description of every step to make it more logical (bare in mind I was speeded out of my brains while typing it so pardon the language):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34861509/929999

Check that out and see if that is in your ballpark of what you hand in mind band best for luck to your journey.