# Difference between pyglet and pygame, in simple words?

Tags: python, api, pygame, pyglet

There are many questions dealing with pyglet and pygame, but what I want to know is difference in theses two, in simple terms.

Not in technical terms, not experimental features and all that.

They are both libraries, both API, both for creation of games and multimedia apps, right?

Just in plain English, for someone like me, relative begginer, who has finished course about Python in Codecademy and read Head first Python book.

Comment: how about just hovering your mouse over the two tags? that's about as plain/simple as you can get

Comment: While this is a pretty *basic* question, I disagree with the close vote - This is a question that has a definitive answer (even though it may not be very long ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pyglet is a wrapper around OpenGL, while Pygame is wrapper around SDL.

[OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/) is primarily concerned with 3d rendering, while [SDL](http://libsdl.org/)

> is a cross-platform development library designed to provide low level access to audio, keyboard, mouse, joystick, and graphics hardware via OpenGL and Direct3D.

Comment: The quote was not a typo - I yanked that text directly from the SDL site, hence it's a quote

Answer (score 1):

`PyGame` is low-level library. You have to do all on your own - starting at `mainloop` and all functions called by `mainloop`. You can do it in different ways.

(And you can learn something about `mainloops` in `Pyglet`, `Tkinter`, `PyQt`, `wxPython` and other `GUIs`, not only in Python)

Pyglet is framework - it has already `mainloop` and you can't change it and you can't see how it works. You override functions which `mainloop` calls. You have to keep its rules.

Comment: I'm down-voting this for two purposes. Saying you can't change the "main loop" of Pyglet is insane to say. You can always override any python function by using [Decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/), further more have a good look at this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846635/pyglet-image-rendering/34861509#34861509 where I've replaced the `mainloop` function with my own. Also `PyGame` is not a low-level library, it's a abstraction layer **ON TOP** of low level libraries such as `OpenGL`. I hope I'm not only on a rant here but it looks like you've mixed it up.

Comment: Further more, saying that `You have to keep its rules` is absurd. Again, have a look at my example and reconsider your statement. I've written my entire `mainloop`, replaced all the "rules" that you claim is impossible to rewrite. I even create a framework out of Pyglet, on it's own it is not a framework at all since there are no UI classes or pre-defined functions for operations except for low level GL operations (such as vertices etc).

Answer (score -3):

I've tried pyglet and pygame and rate pygame as the best .